# How to perform natural (lexicographic) sorting in R?

Tags: r, sorting, natural-sort, r-faq

Is there a [natural sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order) for R?

Say I had a character vector like so:

```
seq.names <- c('abc21', 'abc2', 'abc1', 'abc01', 'abc4', 'abc201', '1b', '1a')
```

I'd like to sort it aphanumerically, so I get back this:

```
c('1a', '1b', 'abc1', 'abc01', 'abc2', 'abc4', 'abc21', 'abc201')
```

Does this exist somewhere, or should I start coding?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I don't think "alphanumeric sort" means what you think it means.

In any case, looks like you want mixedsort, part of [gtools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gtools/index.html).

```
> install.packages('gtools')
[...]
> require('gtools')
Loading required package: gtools
> n
[1] "abc21"  "abc2"   "abc1"   "abc01"  "abc4"   "abc201" "1b"     "1a"    
> mixedsort(n)
[1] "1a"     "1b"     "abc1"   "abc01"  "abc2"   "abc4"   "abc21"  "abc201"
```

Comment: Excellent! Is alphanumeric sort not this right term for this? Have I been calling it the wrong thing all along?

Comment: Alphanumeric sort would like that what is returned from the R sort() function. Each character is evaluated based on ASCII value of the position. Smaller values are sorted first.  In this case, "abc01" would be before "abc1" because ASCII value "0" (48) is smaller than "1" (49) for position 4.

Comment: I've typically used the term "natural order sort" after one of the first widely used pieces of software to do this (http://www.naturalordersort.org/).  Jeff Atwood even wrote an blog post about it (http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html).

Answer (score 17):

Natural sorting is available in the `stringr`/`stringi` packages with the functions `str_sort()`/`stri_sort()`. Switching between alphanumeric and natural sorting is controlled by the 'numeric' argument.

```
library(stringr)
# library(stringi)

str_sort(seq.names, numeric = TRUE)
# stri_sort(seq.names, numeric = TRUE)

[1] "1a"     "1b"     "abc1"   "abc01"  "abc2"   "abc4"   "abc21"  "abc201"
```

The companion function `str_order()` / `stri_order()` returns the indices to arrange the vector in (by default) ascending order:

```
str_order(seq.names, numeric = TRUE)
# stri_order(seq.names, numeric = TRUE)

[1] 8 7 3 4 2 5 1 6

seq.names[str_order(seq.names, numeric = TRUE)]

[1] "1a"     "1b"     "abc1"   "abc01"  "abc2"   "abc4"   "abc21"  "abc201"
```