# Sort a vector by a substring

Tags: r, arrays, string, sorting, substring

Hi I have a list of files:

```
    "1_EX-P1-H2.3000"    "10_EX-P1-H2.3002"   "100_EX-P1-H2.3074" 
    "1004_EX-P1-H2.4059" "1006_EX-P1-H2.4070" "2_EX-P1-H2.3000" "3_EX-P1-H2.3000" "4_EX-P1-H2.3000" 
    "5_EX-P1-H2.3001"
```

I want to sort not by lexicographically order but buy the order of the first number before the "_", these numbers go from 1 to 1000. So as result I should obtain:

```
    "1_EX-P1-H2.3000"    "2_EX-P1-H2.3000" "3_EX-P1-H2.3000" "4_EX-P1-H2.3000" 
    "5_EX-P1-H2.3001"    "10_EX-P1-H2.3002"   "100_EX-P1-H2.3074" 
    "1004_EX-P1-H2.4059" "1006_EX-P1-H2.4070"
```

Comment: This seems like the same as [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65131628/903061), and the same solution works - notice Akrun's solution is the same as the [top answer to the duplicate of your old question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2778060/903061)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the OP mentioned to `order` based on the first number before the `_`, we can use `parse_number` from `readr` to extract the first numeric substring, `order` and use that to rearrange the vector

```
v1[order(readr::parse_number(v1))]
#[1] "1_EX-P1-H2.3000"    "2_EX-P1-H2.3000"    "3_EX-P1-H2.3000"    "4_EX-P1-H2.3000"    "5_EX-P1-H2.3001"    "10_EX-P1-H2.3002"  
#[7] "100_EX-P1-H2.3074"  "1004_EX-P1-H2.4059" "1006_EX-P1-H2.4070"
```

---

Or using `sub` to remove the substring, `order`

```
v1[order(as.numeric(sub("_.*", "", v1)))]
#[1] "1_EX-P1-H2.3000"    "2_EX-P1-H2.3000"    "3_EX-P1-H2.3000"    "4_EX-P1-H2.3000"    "5_EX-P1-H2.3001"    "10_EX-P1-H2.3002"  
#[7] "100_EX-P1-H2.3074"  "1004_EX-P1-H2.4059" "1006_EX-P1-H2.4070"
```

---

Or another option is `mixedsort` from `gtools`

```
gtools::mixedsort(v1)
```

-output

```
#[1] "1_EX-P1-H2.3000"    "2_EX-P1-H2.3000"    "3_EX-P1-H2.3000"    "4_EX-P1-H2.3000"    "5_EX-P1-H2.3001"    "10_EX-P1-H2.3002"  
#[7] "100_EX-P1-H2.3074"  "1004_EX-P1-H2.4059" "1006_EX-P1-H2.4070"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("1_EX-P1-H2.3000", "10_EX-P1-H2.3002", "100_EX-P1-H2.3074", 
"1004_EX-P1-H2.4059", "1006_EX-P1-H2.4070", "2_EX-P1-H2.3000", 
"3_EX-P1-H2.3000", "4_EX-P1-H2.3000", "5_EX-P1-H2.3001")
```